# What happens if Same Provider registered in two modules and if a module imports both the modules

Tags: angular

I have made `LogService` as provider in two modules. Now in my AppModule I am importing both the modules. Since we have registered provider at two modules, I think we will have two instances of `LogService` at two module levels. Now when we import the both in the AppModule which instance are we going to use? Will it be the first imported module provider or last imported module provider? Please take a look at the following code

```
log.service.ts
--------------
@Injectable()
export class LogService {
   private data: number = 45;
}

log.module.ts
-------------
import {LogService} from "./log.service"; 
@NgModule({providers : [LogService]})
export class LogModule{}

logger.module.ts
----------------
import {LogService} from "./log.service"; 
@NgModule({providers : [LogService]})
export class LoggerModule{}

app.module.ts
-------------
@NgModule({imports : [BrowserModule, LogModule, LoggerModule]})
export class AppModule{}

app.component.ts
----------------
import {LogService} from "./log.service"; 
@Component({})
export class AppComponent{
   // will the instance be from LogModule or LoggerModule?
   // If I want to explicitly get the instance of LoggerModule then How do I specify?
   constructor(private logService: LogService){}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't LogService instance be based on your LogService import statement in app.component.ts?

Comment: @AshishBajpai the statement imports the log.service.ts and not the log.module.ts nor looger.module.ts. Please look at the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A service should only be registered with the injector one time, meaning it should only be listed in the `providers` array of one module.

Consider building a `core module` for your shared services as detailed here: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#the-core-module

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';

import { CommonModule }      from '@angular/common';

import { TitleComponent }    from './title.component';
import { UserService }       from './user.service';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ TitleComponent ],
  exports:      [ TitleComponent ],
  providers:    [ UserService ]
})
export class CoreModule {
}
```

The Angular docs say this with regard to which service "wins": https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-two-modules-provide-the-same-service

> When two imported modules, loaded at the same time, list a provider
>   with the same token, the second module's provider "wins". That's
>   because both providers are added to the same injector.

But anecdotal evidence does not seem to match with what it says here.  Devs that have accidentally registered a service multiple times found that it appeared to create multiple instances. So values set in the service from one component were not available to be retrieved from another component.

Comment: From reading the docs I think the last imported module service will be injected at root level. In my case I think it will be LoggerModule but can we actually specify the instance by specifying the module

Comment: I'm pretty sure multiple instances come only from lazy loaded modules (which get their own root scope) and when providers are registered in components or directives. For lazy loaded modules implement `forRoot()` and provider the service there, then import this lazy module using `imports: [MyModulde.forRoot()]`. For non-lazy-loaded modules it doesn't matter how often it is provided, only one instance will be created.